# Automation data into data extention

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs, automationstudio, wsproxy

I found a script for retrieving automation data on https://www.ssjsdocs.xyz/automation-studio/automations/retrieve/all.html. I still learning SSJS and can't figure out how to store this kind of information in a DE. I allready created the DE and tried different versions of  Platform.Function.InsertData but with no results. There are no errors but the DE remains empty. Has anyone by chance tried this themselves?

Answer (score 0):

So, this can likely be handled using the script below.

Note, that you may need to update lines 66-84 using the example on line 67.

In your data extension, make sure CustomerKey is the primary key.

And then update the variable on line 8 with the data extension external key you would like to write the information to.

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1");

var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

// Update the variable below to contain the external key of the data extension you would like to update.
var automationDE = "ABC123"; 

try {

function retrieveAllAutomations() {

    var out = [],
        moreData = true,
        reqID = data = null;

    var cols = [
        "Name",
        "Description",
        "CustomerKey",
        "IsActive",
        "CreatedDate",
        "ModifiedDate",
        "Status",
        "ProgramID",
        "CategoryID",
        "LastRunTime",
        "ScheduledTime",
        "LastSaveDate",
        "ModifiedBy",
        "LastSavedBy",
        "CreatedBy",
        "AutomationType",
        "RecurrenceID"
    ];  

    var filter = {
        Property: 'Status',
        SimpleOperator: 'IN',
        Value: [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    };

    var opts = {
        BatchSize: 300
    };

    var props = {
        QueryAllAccounts: false
    };

    while (moreData) {

        moreData = false;

        if(reqID) props.ContinueRequest = reqID;

        var data = api.retrieve("Automation", cols, filter, opts, props);

        if (data) {
            moreData = data.HasMoreRows;
            reqID = data.RequestID;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
                out.push(data.Results[i]);

                var name = data.Results[i].Name;
                // alternatively, this may require data.Results[i].Properties[0].Value
                // change the value in properties to change the value you retreive aka 0 = name, 1 = description, 2 = customerkey, etc.
                var description = data.Results[i].Description;
                var customerkey = data.Results[i].CustomerKey;
                var isActive = data.Results[i].IsActive;
                var createdDate = data.Results[i].CreatedDate;
                var modifiedDate = data.Results[i].ModifiedDate;
                var status = data.Results[i].Status;
                var programID = data.Results[i].ProgramID;
                var categoryID = data.Results[i].CategoryID;
                var lastRunTime = data.Results[i].LastRunTime;
                var scheduledTime = data.Results[i].ScheduledTime;
                var lastSaveDate = data.Results[i].LastSavedDate;
                var modifiedBy = data.Results[i].ModifiedBy;
                var lastSavedBy = data.Results[i].LastSavedBy;
                var createdBy = data.Results[i].CreatedBy;
                var automationType = data.Results[i].AutomationType;
                var recurrenceID = data.Results[i].RecurrenceID;

                var props = [
                    {
                        "Name": "Name",
                        "Value": name
                        // Text field
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Description",
                        "Value": description
                        // Text field
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "CustomerKey",
                        "Value": customerKey
                        // Text field
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "IsActive",
                        "Value": isActive
                        // Boolean
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "CreatedDate",
                        "Value": createdDate
                        // Date
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "ModifiedDate",
                        "Value": modifiedDate
                        // Date
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Status",
                        "Value": status
                        // Text / Number
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "ProgramID",
                        "Value": programID
                        // Text
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "CategoryID",
                        "Value": categoryID
                        // Number
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "LastRunTime",
                        "Value": lastRunTime
                        // Date
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "ScheduledTime",
                        "Value": scheduledTime
                        // Date
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "LastSaveDate",
                        "Value": lastSaveDate
                        // Date
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "ModifiedBy",
                        "Value": modifiedBy
                        // Text / Number
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "LastSavedBy",
                        "Value": lastSavedBy
                        // Text / Number
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "CreatedBy",
                        "Value": createdBy
                        // Text / Number
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "AutomationType",
                        "Value": automationType
                        // Text
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "RecurrenceID",
                        "Value": recurrenceID
                        // Text / Number
                    }
                ];

                var options = {
                    SaveOptions: [
                        {
                            PropertyName: 'CustomerKey',
                            SaveAction: 'UpdateAdd'
                        }
                    ]
                };

                var addInfo = api.updateItem("DataExtensionObject", {
                    CustomerKey: automationDE,
                    Properties: props
                }, options);

            }
        }
    }
}

} catch(err) {
    Write(Stringify(err));
}
```

Comment: Thanks KCWright. Unfortunately no results in my DE. I even updated the lines 66-84. My DE has the exact attribute fields as needed. Also the attribute types are matching. Is there something else I missed?

Comment: Out of the box thinking, should this script running in the parrent BU or does it not matter?